i am getting permission issue while connecting ec2 to local system
I am making  stock market real time analysis project,
But i am getting stuck in connecting aws ec2 to local system refer this image
I am getting permission issue in windows which is given in picture Please help i am having placement
please give steps to solve this

A Permission denied error means that you are successfully connecting with the EC2 instance but it is rejecting the private key. You can get a bit more information by using ssh -vvv ... where it should show you attempts to use the key. Have you ever managed to connect to this instance before? Did you select that key when the instance was launched?

check for the .pem file permissions. this should be 400.
